# Driver Testing Error popup in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Everytime when I open Visual Studio, a pop up display with message:

```
Driver Testing

Could not load test information. Error Object reference not set to an instance of an Object..
```

I am not sure how to get rid of this message. What is the cause of this error and how to rectify it?

Comment: this happend to me after installing wdk (windows driver kit)

Comment: Uninstalling and installing Visual Studio solved this problem in my machine.

Answer (score 5):

Old, but here's my solution: Just uninstall the WDM package under 'Manage Extensions'.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant WDK - but this was the right answer (at least in my situation). The error appeared after removing the Windows Driver Kit via Add/Remove Programs, prior to removing the corresponding Visual Studio 2017 extension (via VS Extension Manager).

Answer (score 1):

i got wdk from here [wdk](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2026156).
downloaded it to '\Downloads\Windows Kits\10\WDK' .
installed it and checked wdk vs extension,problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've uninstalled WDK and started seeing this error.  If there's a "Driver" menu group just above the "Manage Extensions" menu item, uninstall the WDK extension to suppress this pesky error.

[image: VS2022 Extensions Menu]